# How to use Persons object in stripe.net NuGet Package 15.3.2 version

Tags: c#, nuget, stripe-payments, nuget-package

currently our account requests API version is 2018-02-06 and we are upgrading to 2020-03-02

so As part of Accounts API Argument [Changes](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/required-updates/accounts-arguments#individual-arguments)

[image]

Now few fields are managed with **Persons** object

latest NuGet packages supports this

[image]

but it is not avaible in old versions. **can we manage this without updating the NuGet package?**

Answer (score 1):

The best and recommended option is to upgrade the NuGet package. That said, it's entirely possible to form your own HTTP request manually outside of the library.

Here are the available options:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/persons/update?lang=curl

Here is some more information about making the HTTP request directly from C#:

[How to make HTTP POST web request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/how-to-make-http-post-web-request)